# npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from

Tags: npm

I ran cmd as an administrator and typed this command:

`npm init wasm-app www`

But it does not work. I was wondering why? It shows this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Rathod\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\16292" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Harsh Rathod\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-04T10_05_04_450Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-wasm-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given below hack worked for me:

```
npm install -g create-wasm-app
npx create-wasm-app www
```